# How to know if an application has stopped processing a task?

Tags: windows

An application/executable is processing a file in Windows 7.

I need a notification from Windows saying that this file has stopped processing. Is it possible or are there alternatives?

Comment: Pedantically, this is not generally possible. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Windows' Task Manager and check out if the task is in progress, or terminated.

Press <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> to go to Task Manager. It's very easy and you can find out whether your task is working or not.

Comment: programmatically using code - can u suggest a windows API etc.,

Comment: @dhaval for that you should be asking your question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your programming language.  But in C with Windows-API if you create the task via CreateProcess() you can supply a PROCESS_INFORMATION structure, from which you can get a process handle as a result.

```
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pi= { 0, };
 BOOL success= CreateProcess(....., &pi);
```

Then you can use WaitForSingleObject() to either wait for completion, or with a timeout of zero, a return code of WAIT_FAILED or WAIT_TIMEOUT indicates that the process is still running.

```
 DWORD result= WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 0);
 if (result==WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
   // Process is complete
 }
```

Details: 
[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202783.aspx)